# How to add machine name to logfile name using log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

Is there a way to add machine name to logfile name in log4j?

This is my situation: I have 4 machines/servers running Weblogic and each machine/server is running 2 instances/nodes of the JVM application (provided by a vendor); this application generates logs using log4j; however logfile names are all the same for all machines/servers and that causes me too much trouble when I have to review or gather logs for troubleshooting.

I've been already able to distinguish instances/nodes among them by using the following - weblogic.Name property:

```
<appender name="DFe" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/dfe_${weblogic.Name}.log"/>
```

Now I need to distinguish logfile names by machine/server name as well. How to do that? Is there any weblogic.Machine property or something?

Example: my machine/server name is "ausplsynapp03" and instance/node names are "track60800-01" and "track60800-02"; so my logfile names would be "dfe_ausplsynapp03_track60800-01.log" and "dfe_ausplsynapp03_track60800-02.log".

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `${weblogic.Name}` in your file name or appender pattern you are actually using value from WebLogic JVM argument.

If you can add custom argument to JMV arguments you can use it for logging purposes.

Otherwise you can check for other WebLogic arguments here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/admin_ref/weblogicServer.html
Maybe `weblogic.Domain` will work for you.

If you are OK with having host in log message you can set MDC/NDC attribute and output it to log message using `x` or `%X{key}` (reference https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Aleh

Answer (score 0):

Try to set environment property like below
System.setProperty(“serverHostName“, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());

then use it in your log4j.xml
as below

param name=”file” value=”${serverHostName}.log”

Comment: Thanks for the tip Arun